# Trouble passing struct pointers in C to create a sequential list

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, function-pointers

I have a struct defined here

```
typedef struct {
char name[10];
int idBadge;
} Employee;
```

I want to populate one instance of this struct using this function call:

```
void EmployeeCall (char *name, int badgeNumber, Employee *E){
    E = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
    strcpy(E->name,name);
    E->idBadge = badgeNumber;
}
```

and then, I want to retrieve a given piece of information using a call like this:

```
int EmployeeBadge (Employee E){
    return(E.idBadge);
}
```

I call these functions from my Main bellow:

```
int main(void){
    Employee a;
    int badgeNumber;

    int badgeNumberA = 1028;
    char *namePtrA = "Fred";

    EmployeeCall( namePtrA, badgeNumberA, &a );

    badgeNumber = EmployeeBadge(a);
    printf("%d\n",badgeNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

When I call them, it all compiles correctly however, the return on EmployeeBadge is incorrect.  It returns the int as if nothing was placed into the struct; *badgeNumber = 32767*

How is it possible to create a struct variable that can be passed by both value and reference?  Would I need another Employee variable that is a pointer and assign Employee a to it for the EmployeeCall function?

Comment: ` E = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Student));`???

Comment: You can dereference `*e` for `int i = employeeBadge(*e);` If declared static, I bet compiler will optimize the unneeded parts away -- even though `static int employeeBadge(Employee *E) { return E->badgeID; }` is at least as good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you code should not need to allocate a new Employee, change your `EmployeeCall` to

```
void EmployeeCall (char *name, int badgeNumber, Employee *E){

    strcpy(E->name,name);
    E->idBadge = badgeNumber;
}
```

Comment: So there is not need to malloc any extra memory to this then? What about when I am to destroy that Employee information, would it be possible to use Free(E) then?

Comment: this way, you don't need to free (E), since it is allocated at the stack. Its memory will be automatically reclaimed.

Answer (score 2):

Your main function has already reserved memory for the Employee and the pointer 'E' will remain local to the function. You can simply omit the `malloc`;

The other solution is to pass a pointer to pointer and let CallEmployee populate:

```
main()
{
        Employee *e;
        EmployeeCall( ..., &e);
}

void EmployeeCall (char *name, int badgeNumber, Employee **E)
{
   *E = malloc(sizeof(Employee));  // No cast needed
}
```

Comment: The pointer to pointer is my preferred solution, even though the other solution "works". It works for now, but won't work for 1 million employees due to _stack overflow_.

Comment: For the scope of this, that is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this

```
E = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
```

should be

```
E = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
```

BUT, since you pass in the employee here:

```
EmployeeCall( namePtrA, badgeNumberA, &a ); // &a is the employee
```

You simply want to remove the call to malloc:

```
// don't need this E = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited it to be correct. Not relevant.

Comment: See the other part about not needing the malloc, or see John's answer.

Comment: This is because there has already been memory allocated to it correct?

Comment: When you say 'Employee a;' that puts enough memory for an Employee on the stack. That's different than using malloc to get memory from the heap.